# Since Softbank Robotics Store Closed, how can I add additional language to Pepper?

Tags: pepper

Previously, languages are supported and installable via 'Store' page.
Softbank Robotics closed the community and store page (store shows 503 error.).

Is there any way to download and install additional language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NAOqi 2.8 and earlier, there is still [this store](https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/), but I do not know how limited it is.

Answer (score 1):

The new SoftBank store is available at https://command-center.softbankrobotics.com/. Although not well documented, the language packs seem to be available there. First, the access needs to be approved by the support.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I should contact?

Comment: Probably [create an account](https://accounts.softbankrobotics.com/#/create) and then ask [support](https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/support) to allow the access to the [store](https://command-center.softbankrobotics.com/).